# Can only either have output or input on my USB sound card when having headphones plugged in. No profiles that use both

Tags: audio, pulseaudio, alsa, usb-audio

I recently bought a usb audio device so I won't have to unplug and plug headphone/speakers everytime I wanted to switch between them.

The audio card has input for mic and one for speakers/headphones. Chipset is C-Media CM108.

I checked the Audio device using `pacmd list-cards` and it seems to be a problem with the profiles? Does it need to have a combined one to be able to both hear sound and use mic?

```
    properties:
        alsa.card = "2"
        alsa.card_name = "USB Audio Device"
        alsa.long_card_name = "GeneralPlus USB Audio Device at usb-0000:04:00.1-3.4, full speed"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_usb_audio"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:04:00.1-usb-0:3.4:1.0"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.2/0000:01:00.0/0000:02:08.0/0000:04:00.1/usb1/1-3/1-3.4/1-3.4:1.0/sound/card2"
        udev.id = "usb-GeneralPlus_USB_Audio_Device-00"
        device.bus = "usb"
        device.vendor.id = "1b3f"
        device.vendor.name = "Generalplus Technology Inc."
        device.product.id = "2008"
        device.product.name = "USB Audio Device"
        device.serial = "GeneralPlus_USB_Audio_Device"
        device.string = "2"
        device.description = "USB Audio Device"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-usb"
    profiles:
        input:mono-fallback: Mono Input (priority 1, available: unknown)
        input:multichannel-input: Multichannel Input (priority 1, available: unknown)
        output:analog-stereo: Analog Stereo Output (priority 6500, available: unknown)
        output:iec958-stereo: Digital Stereo (IEC958) Output (priority 5500, available: unknown)
        off: Off (priority 0, available: unknown)
```

Alsamixer has two settings for the card. Speaker and mic which both are unmuted and full volume. I'm not sure if it matters it says it's a speaker instead of headphones.

pavucontrol lists the profiles listed above. When I select an input profile it detects the mic just fine and it works.  And When I choose an output profile I can hear sound from the headphones as well but no input devices are available with that profile.

I tried to follow the guide at [archlinux's wiki for pulseaudio](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PulseAudio/Examples). The chapter 'Independent analog and digital outputs on the same card' has some examples how to create combined profiles but I either didn't do this one correctly or the profile needs to be listed already on the device for it to work.

The usb audio device works as expected when tested in windows. And the channels work independently just fine on linux. Just using both seems not to be possible.

Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: let me start by saying that i know very little about how to solve your problem .... it appears that you need a gamer headset profile for this to work ... perhaps the solution is an adapter plug that would cause the sound card to detect the headphone as a gamer headset

Comment: maybe you need to buy a better sound card. one that can use both the output and the input at the same time. i think that sound card can't do it. i have the same sound card. a usb sound card.